# How to add placeholder color property to Autocomplete field in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

I want to add placeholder color property to my autocomplete field. I used the following codes to show autocomplete in my form.My Xmal Code is follows and I used  xmlns:auto="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms".
   I cant bind the placeholderColor property to my xmal page.but AutoCompleteViewModel contains the definition for placeholderColor property .How to solve this issue.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Margin="20,10,20,0"  BackgroundColor="#91BC47">     
    <auto:AutoCompleteView x:Name="Auto_Area" Text="Select Area"  TextColor="White" IsVisible="True" Placeholder="select Area" PlaceholderColor="{Binding PlaceholderColor}"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"
        SearchTextColor="Yellow" 
        SelectedCommand="{Binding CellSelectedCommand}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
        ShowSearchButton="False"
        SuggestionBackgroundColor="#91BC47"
        Margin="5,0,0,0"
        SuggestionItemDataTemplate="{StaticResource SugestionItemTemplate}"
        Suggestions="{Binding Items,
        Mode=TwoWay}" />                  
</StackLayout>   


public class AutoCompleteViewModel : XLabs.Forms.Mvvm.ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<AutoComplete> _items;
    private Command<string> _searchCommand;
    private Command<AutoComplete> _cellSelectedCommand;
    private AutoComplete _selectedItem;
    private Color _placeholderColor;

    public AutoCompleteViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<AutoComplete>();

        Items = App._areas1.OrderBy(p => p).Select(p => new AutoComplete
        {
            Name = p,
            ID = 1
        }).ToObservableCollection();
    }

    public static BindableProperty PlaceholderColorProperty
        = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceholderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(EditorControl), Color.White);

    public Color PlaceholderColor
    {
        get
        {
            return  _placeholderColor;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _placeholderColor, value);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AutoComplete> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _items, value);
        }
    }

    public Command<AutoComplete> CellSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _cellSelectedCommand ?? (_cellSelectedCommand = new Command<AutoComplete>(parameter => Debug.WriteLine(parameter.ID + parameter.Name)));
        }
    }

    public Command<string> SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _searchCommand ?? (_searchCommand = new Command<string>(
                obj => { },
                obj => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ToString())));
        }
    }

    public AutoComplete SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be a missing namespace. Besides that, BindableProperties are supposed to be implemented in the View, e.g. a Page or a Button. The ViewModel is the one that binds to these afterwards

Comment: @Csharpest 32 can you share the code or link to set placeholder color property in autocomplete field?

Comment: Put the BindableProperty into your view, and create a property in the viewmodel: `private Color _placeholderColor; public Color PlaceholderColor get => _placeholderColor; set => SetProperty(ref _placeholderColor, value);`  And then either in xaml of your view: PlaceholderColor = "{Binding YourViewModel}" or in the codebehind of the view ctor: `this.SetBinding(PlaceholderColorProperty, "Placeholder");` "PlaceholderColor" represents the name of the property in the viewmodel, like the way you do it in xaml

Comment: @Csharpest 32 I put the BindableProperty into the the View.But i didn't get the PlaceholderColor property in xmal or c# page

Comment: Edit your post and add the view code

Comment: @Csharpest 32 i updated my code.

Comment: You did not do it the way i said it. Following should be in the autocompleteview: `public static BindableProperty PlaceholderColorProperty
              = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceholderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(AutoCompleteView), Color.White);` and this is important: (u dont have that) `public Color PlaceholderColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(PlaceholderColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PlaceholderColorProperty, value); }
        }`

Comment: @Csharpest 32 I added in autoCompleteView.And i set the PlaceholderColor in xaml page.still the color is not changed

Comment: Oh I think you might misunderstand something. Just adding a property called "PlaceholderColor" won't make the placeholder color change. Either there is a PlaceholderColor property on this xlab.autocomplete control, or what you will have to do is create a custom renderer for the platforms you need. If you dont know custom renderers, you gotta look into them, serach for "xamarin custom renderers". But the best solution, if you want to keep every functionality of the autocomplete view + placeholdercolor, then go with the solution mentioned by Nick in the comments below

Answer (score 1):

Your `BindableProperty` needs to be added to your `AutoCompleteView` not your `AutoCompleteViewModel`

```
public class AutoCompleteView
{
    public static BindableProperty PlaceholderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceholderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(AutoCompleteView), Color.White);

    public Color PlaceholderColor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Color)GetValue(PlaceholderColorProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PlaceholderColorProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And then it just needs to be bound to the PlaceholderColor in your ViewModel.

```
public class AutoCompleteViewModel : XLabs.Forms.Mvvm.ViewModel
{
    private Color _placeholderColor = Color.White;

    public Color PlaceholderColor
    {
        get
        {
           return  _placeholderColor;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _placeholderColor, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Nick AutoCompleteView class is from XLabs.Forms.Controls. And i cant edit or adding anything on to that.I have only AutoCompleteViewModel class,ViewModelLocator.cs and MainViewModel.cs are in my project to support AutoCompleteView.where i added the BindableProperty

Comment: Xlabs is [opensource](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) so there's nothing stopping you from editing it or copying the class over to your project

Comment: Or you can make a new control that extends `AutoCompleteView` and do it there